# What did i do wrong in my understand of save data, need to make an easy app for adding to numbers together and save the result for adding more to it

Tags: sharedpreferences

package com.example.application.myapplication`enter code here`

import android.content.Context`enter code here`
import android.os.Bundle`enter code here`
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        var c = Antal.text.toString().toInt()
        val MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
        val editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        editor.putString("name", "Elena")
        editor.putInt("idName", 12)
        editor.apply()


        val prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined") value.

        val idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0)

        Navn.text = name.toString()`enter code here`
        Alder.text = idName.toString()

    button.setOnClickListener {
        val pref = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var a = Antal.text.toString().toInt();`enter code here`
        Alder.text = pref.edit(a + c)`enter code here`
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is my first time and english isent my birth language. And it is only my 3 app.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  and also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)